# Stubbing functions in simulations

Tags: c, embedded, simulation, mocking

I'm working on an embedded C project that depends on some external HW. I wish to stub out the code accessing these parts, so I can simulate the system without using any HW. Until now I have used some macros but this forces me to change a little on my production code, which I would like to avoid.

### Example:

```
stub.h
#ifdef _STUB_HW
#define STUB_HW(name) Stub_##name
#else /*_STUB_HW*/
#define STUB_HW(name) name
#endif /*_STUB_HW*/

my_hw.c
WORD STUB_HW(clear_RX_TX)()
{ /* clear my rx/tx buffer on target HW */ }

test_my_hw.c
#ifdef _STUB_HW
WORD clear_RX_TX()
{ /* simulate clear rx/tx buffer on target HW */ }
```

With this code I can turn on/off the stubbing with the preprocessor tag `_STUB_HW` 
Is there a way to acomplish this without having to change my prod code, and avoiding a lot of ifdefs. And I won't mix prod and test code in the same file if I can avoid it. I don't care how the test code looks as long as I can keep as much as possible out of the production code.

### Edit:

Would be nice if it was posible to select/rename functions without replacing the whole file. Like take all functions starting on `nRF_##` and giving then a new name and then inserting `test_nRF_##` to `nRF_##` if it is posible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just make two files ActualDriver.c and StubDriver.c containing exactly the same function names. By making two builds linking the production code against the different objects there is no naming conflicts. This way the production code contains no testing or conditional code.

Comment: Actually a good working option. Not sure if it is the best solution for me. See edit.

Comment: Acepting at lest as ong as noone else figures out a better solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Gerhard said, use a common header file "driver.h" and separate hardware layer implementation files containing the actual and stubbed functions.

In eclipse, I have two targets and I "exclude from build" the driver.c file that is not to be used and make sure the proper one is included in the build. Eclipse then generates the makefile at build time.

Another issue to point out is to ensure you are defining fixed size integers so your code behaves the same from an overflow perspective. (Although from your code sample I can see you are doing that.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above. The standard solution to this is to define an opaque abstracted set of function calls that are the "driver" to the hw, and then call that in the main program. Then provide two different driver implementations, one for hw, one for sw. The sw variant will simulate the IO effect of the hw in some appropriate way.

Note that if the goal is at a lower level, i.e., writing code where each hardware access is to be simulated rather than entire functions, it might be a bit tricker. But here, different "write_to_memory" and "read_from_memory" functions (or macros, if speed on target is essential) could be defined.

There is no need in either case to change the names of functions, just have two different batch files, make files, or IDE build targets (depending on what tools you are using).

Finally, in many cases a better technical solution is to go for a full-blown target system simulator, such as [Qemu](http://bellard.org/qemu/), [Simics](http://www.virtutech.com), [SystemC](http://www.systemc.org), [CoWare](http://www.coware.com), [VaST](http://www.vastsystems.com), or similar.  This lets you run the same code all the time, and instead you build a model of the hardware that works like the actual hardware from the perspective of the software. It does take a much larger up-front investment, but for many projects it is well worth the effort.  It basically gets rid of the nasty issue of having different builds for target and host, and makes sure you always use your cross-compiler with deployment build options.  Note that many embedded compiler suites come with some basic such simulation ability built in.